# Extract multiple ROI pixel value from multiple images

Tags: matlab, mask, roi

I have a programming challenge out of reach of my very stammering Matlab expertise. I have a list of images and list of ROI mask in a cell array, and I want to extract mean pixel value of each ROI individually,
My code goes like this :

```
files=dir('*.tif');
for f=1:length(files)
image=im2double(imread(files(f).name));       
pixel_value(:,f)=cellfun(@(x) extractROIpixel(x,image), mask);    
% apply extractROIpixel on each cell of the mask array
end

function [ mean_pixel_value ] = extractROIpixel( mask, img )
      mask=im2double(mask);
      mask(mask == 0) = NaN;
      mask_area=mask.*img;
      mean_pixel_value=mean(mask_area(~isnan(mask_area)));  
end
```

This works, but very slow (<5min), I have 400 images to process with a 200 long cell array of masks (200 ROIs).
I'm sure it is due to poor design, as Matlab is widely used for this kind of image processing tasks, but I can't figure out another affordable way to do it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
files=dir('*.tif');
for f=1:length(files)
   image=im2double(imread(files(f).name));
   masked=cellfun(@(x) image.*x, mask);
   stats{f}=cellfun(@(x) regionprops(x, 'MeanIntensity'), masked);
end
```

I did not benchmark the two approaches, so I don't know if it is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but it can not work, as I want to apply the "masked" function to each cell of my mask array, within the same image : in other terms, I have to apply function throughout mask array keeping the image constant and iterate for all my images. Hence my "for" loop on the image list.

Comment: I see. I edited it accordingly. Again, I don't know if `regionprops` is an efficient thing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my attention to the regionprops method, which I did not know of... But it actually takes twice as much time than my extractROIpixel function.

Comment: Ok, good to know. It's pretty convenient, but apparently not very lean.